# Are Democratic members of congress more educated?

Tags: united-states, congress, education

I have read some people on this site talking about how whether or not white Americans have a college degree can change their voting habits. I was thinking about this topic regardless of race in Congress.

Has it been shown that Democratic members of Congress are more educated than their Republican counterparts? Or, vice versa?

I mean based on things like how much post graduate schooling and achievements they have made. I think something about vocabulary could also count. This needs to be educational statistics that can be *measured* in an objective and nonpartisan manner.

Comment: There is no *objective* way to usefully measure the amount of education.  It's what you do with it, not what paper you have or letters after (or before) your name.  I'd rather have an uneducated honest person over practically any politician. with rare exceptions.  We need a test for honesty - mandatory lie detector tests for candidates ? :-)

Comment: @StephenG what in the world are you talking about? Education is a formal process that is trivially measured (and is, all the time, for government purposes). You may be confusing it with knowledge.

Comment: @Davor Even comparing the education of two courses that produce the same qualification and take the same time is problematic.  Otherwise why would people consider a qualification from one school better than another producing the same actual qualification in the same period ?  It is *not* an objective process.

Comment: @StephenG - OK, so you are definitely confusing education with knowledge attained.

Comment: @Davor I fear to ask what your definition for education is if it is not knowledge gained ?  What is the purpose of education except to impart knowledge ?

Comment: @StephenG the question simply asks for formal education in a measurable way (in US high school, college, doctorate, etc.) and its distribution between the two large parties in US Congress. While I agree with you that many degrees cannot be compared regarding the knowledge obtained therein, your challenge of the premises of the question would probably make it unanswerable within the scope of this site.

Comment: @StephenG if purpose of education is to impart knowledge, than by definition they are not the same, no? And anyway, education is expressed purely in terms of *certification* AKA degrees. Different countries will have different standards, but where I'm from there are 8 levels ranging from elementary school to doctorate.

Comment: @StephenG "What is the purpose of education except to impart knowledge ?" is a philisophical debate.

Answer (score 23):

Psychologist Jonathan Wai looked at this factor in his 2012 article; *[Investigating America's elite: Cognitive ability, education, and sex differences](https://www.psychologytoday.com/files/attachments/56143/wai-americas-elite-2013.pdf)*, published in the Intelligence journal. His metric for intelligence is based on admission to a highly selective college, working from conclusions drawn by Charles Murray in *Coming Apart: The State of White America, 1960-2010*:

> The average graduate of an elite college is at the 99th centile of IQ
> of the entire population of seventeen-year-olds. This is consistent
> with the median combined Critical Reading and Mathematics scores of
> 1400 or more among the top dozen schools in the most recent U.S. News
> & World Report rankings.
>
> In 2010, a combined score of 1400 put a student at
> about the 97th percentile of all students who took the SAT (based on
> the distribution produced by the known means and standard deviations
> for the two tests and a correlation of +0.7 between them). But the
> number of test-takers in 2010 represented only 36 percent of the
> seventeen-year-olds in the country. Any plausible assumptions about
> the proportion of the 62 percent of seventeenyear-olds who didn’t take
> the SAT who could have gotten a combined score of 1400 or more puts a
> student who actually does score 1400 well into the 99th centile of the
> seventeen-year-old population.

Working from these assumptions, Wai identified 29 universities and liberal arts colleges, 12 law schools, and 12 business schools that met Murray's definition of an elite institution. He then used the [Biographical Directory of the United States Congress](https://bioguideretro.congress.gov/) to investigate the educational records of the Senators & Representatives of the 112th Congress.

[image]

He found that not only were Democrats in both the House and Senate significantly more likely to have attended an Elite School than Republicans, they were also more likely to have attended Harvard. He concludes:

> **Democrats have a higher ability and education level than Republicans**
>
> Research has indicated that individuals who are politically liberal
> are more likely to have higher ability than those who are politically
> conservative in America ([Kanazawa, 2010](http://personal.lse.ac.uk/kanazawa/pdfs/spq2010.pdf)) and Britain ([Deary, Batty, &
> Gale, 2008](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18181782/)). However, this finding pertained to voters rather than
> political leaders those people had elected. This study demonstrates
> that in America, Democrats were more likely than Republicans to have a
> higher percentage of Senate and House members who attended an Elite
> School which places these individuals in the top 1% in ability. Therefore, among the elected elite,
> Democrats had a higher ability and education level, on average, than
> Republicans.

I feel that it's very important to point out the limitations that Wai notes, for example, the approximation of individual ability level based on average test scores at very specific institutions, and the use of these approximated test scores as a proxy for intelligence. However, Wai's article seems like a pretty good objective academic analysis despite these limitations.

Comment: I find the assumptions, and their assumed implications, in this work to be questionable, but it is nevertheless a piece of scholarship on the topic, and is pretty clear about making those assumptions and seeing what you get from them, and so worth pointing out and considering. (+1)

Comment: @zibadawatimmy How do you propose to a better study on this topic? Almost all members of congress have some college education. You can't really compare say a law degree to a physics degree, so distinguishing between degrees from elite institutions seems the most plausible way to go.

Comment: @quarague It can be questionable even if there is no better way

Comment: While interesting, I don't think this answers the OPs question.  Does obtaining a degree from an "Elite School" actually correlate to being more educated?

Comment: @quarague I propose US Politicians College Major and Level versus Party Alignment

Comment: @quarague How about just directly comparing their SAT/ACT scores? Though this has difficulties, because more recent scores are inflated compared to older scores, say from the 80s. Bottom line, attending an 'elite' institution has greater correlation with having money than being intelligent.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/27/magazine/people-dont-bribe-college-officials-to-help-their-kids-they-do-it-to-help-themselves.html explains that at elite schools, "The wealthy launder their privilege by allowing select others to earn their way into its orbit. And the intelligence and success of hardworking peers makes a wealthy wastrel seem qualified by association: Maybe he graduated with straight C’s, a drinking problem and an unearned job at the family business, but he went to *Yale* — isn’t that where smart people go?" Does Wai try to control for that?

Comment: *Wai's article seems like a pretty good objective academic analysis despite these limitations.*  It's an appallingly bad article that does not address the influence of money and power in someone getting into such an institution or the documented cases of privileged people falsifying not just the qualifications for entry, but the entire acadmeic record of their children by using a combination of institutional donations and hiring people to take their tests for them.  Without addressing the extent of these practices the article simply paints a false glossy impression of a corrupt system.

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a mostly useless measure. You know what else highly correlates with being accepted to an elite school? Having wealthy parents, especially if they are part of the political establishment and doubly if they are themselves alumni. Guess what factors also correlate strongly with being a member of Congress... If anything, this is more likely to show that the GOP members at the time of the study were less likely to be raised in wealthy and politically well-connected families.

Comment: @GlenYates The main problem with direct comparison of ACT/SAT scores is that those aren't public information, just as GPAs also aren't. That said, I agree completely regarding the major problems with using having graduated from an "elite" school directly as a measure of "ability and education level," which is laughably absurd.

Comment: While I am not familiar with Jonathan Wai, it is worthy of note that Charles Murray is a very [controversial character](https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate/extremist-files/individual/charles-murray), who's scholarship has garnered [widespread critism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bell_Curve#Criticisms). Any works derivative of Murray's should be closely scrutinized.

Answer (score 21):

Congress is, as a whole, extraordinarily well-educated, especially when compared to the greater population averages.  For decades now the House has had 90% or more of its members have at least a College degree—with 40% having a Doctorate (including [J.D.'s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juris_Doctor)) and another 20% having a Masters—, with more recent Houses being at 94% and above.  It's surprisingly a little hard for me to find accessible party-line breakdowns, as most summaries (from the Congressional Research Service, say) seem to provide statistics only for entire chambers, and do not list party affiliations when naming specific members.

[But here's an article](https://www.chronicle.com/article/in-congress-even-lawmakers-degrees-are-a-partisan-issue/) that breaks down degree composition on a party basis in the House, for the last handful of Congresses or so, up to the 115th Congress (the one Trump was inaugurated under; the current Congress is the 116th, and is a historically well-educated Congress going by the measure of undergrad degrees).  In short, the proportion of members with college degrees has been very high and essentially identical across party lines for several decades.  Democrats are a bit more likely to have gone to a private college, and Republicans correspondingly more likely to have gone to a public one.  There are 11 Democrats in the 115th Congress that went to an Ivy league for their undergrad degree, while only 4 Republicans in the same Congress did.  For the last decade or so Democrats have had the edge on Ivy league educations. If one really values "Ivy league education" as being the "better educated kind", perhaps we could substantiate the claims that Democrats are better educated.  But given that there are over 400 members of the House alone, a mere 15 combined across both parties is a pretty meager sample.

Comment: That 40% figure includes people with a J.D. (Juris Doctor) degree, which requires three years of post-baccalaureate education -- about the same as a master's degree and considerably less than a doctorate in other fields.

Comment: @DavidHammen It does, but having seen the amount of reading and effort required for a J.D., and compared them to requirements for a Master's, I'm not convinced it should be considered particularly comparable to a Master's.  I'd probably rank a J.D. higher than some Ph.D.'s for "hard work and general smarty-pants-ness required". But we'd probably have to start delving well outside the scope of the question to try to distinguish between Doctorates.

Comment: zibadawa timmy, it is common in the hard sciences to take multiple days to digest a 20 page paper. One of the most challenging graduate level classes I took was on Optimal Control Theory, unfortunately taught by a pure mathematician. We made it through the first 60 pages of the text. He made us fill in the blanks in the hand-wavy proofs that are fine for applied mathematics but are anathema to pure mathematicians. (Most instructors skip those first 60 pages.) I learned two things: An optimal control sometime does exist, and to never take an applied math class taught by a pure mathematician.

Comment: @DavidHammen Not sure what your point is.  And I'm a (pure) mathematician, so I'm aware of what it takes there.

Comment: Students of mathematics, computer science, and the physical sciences have to learn early on to read very slowly because authors leave immense blanks as an exercise to be filled in by the reader. That's diametrically opposed to how students of the humanities have to learn to read several hundred pages a week.

Comment: Compare Einstein's 1905 paper on special relativity: 23 pages and **no** references. A humanities paper of comparable length will have hundreds of references.

Comment: @DavidHammen Is your point that mathematicians sit as glorious and resplendent kings upon the intellectual hierarchy, or what?  And what's the relevance to where lawyers rank, vis a vis "doctorate" including "J.D."?  That differing disciplines emphasize differing forms of retention and synthesis is hardly surprising.

Comment: If you can link to the summaries you mention, I can merge with another dataset with names and affiliations

Comment: @zibadawatimmy The point is that you can't say a JD > Master's based on page count alone.

Comment: @DavidHammen You're not wrong, but not all Ph.D.s are in mathematics, Comp Sci, or the physical sciences. I'd guess that the average Ph.D. in those fields has a higher IQ than the average J.D. or even M.D. I'd also guess than the average J.D. has a higher IQ than the average Ph.D. in, say, business, education, English, or music. Not that there's anything wrong with those fields, just that they're not necessarily associated with particularly high average IQs compared to other doctorates.

Comment: Unfortunately, currently, there's one GOP party member who is flaunting the fact that she didn't have any college student loan debts, because she ONLY has a GED.   I agree that it should be separated by major, degree level, and school, because they are not all comparable directly--and we can't see grades,so we don't know if they barely passed.  I mean a degree from an elite university is more so than a party school, based upon curriculum and course rigor same as comparing hard science vs social science vs liberal arts majors.